# Windows 10 Time/Date updating without network connection?

Tags: windows-10, updates, time, date-time, date

Context: Windows 10 Pro

I back-dated my Win 10 Pro machine (rewinded a couple months, had to turn off 'Set time automatically' option), and wanted to make sure that no software was checking the date/time from the internet and turned off all internet connections on my machine.

Everywhere that I could see had the altered date I had used. I accidentally clicked back on the 'Set time automatically' option, and was surprised to see the machine correctly reset itself.

Trying to see if it was perhaps some temporarily cached 'last time' setting, I turned back off the automatic setting, changed date, restarted (confirmed that the Bios date was the correct modified one), confirmed that windows 10 still had the modified date, turned back on the automatic setting and it again was able to resync to the correct date.

Where does Windows 10 synchronize from if it doesn't have access to the outside world? BIOS isn't helping in this case because it has also been changed. Is there another time source on the machine hiding somewhere? Or perhaps some not temporarily cached date/time info?

Thanks!

Comment: Just set the NTP source to be something that's invalid.

Comment: You stated that you "turned off all internet connections". Since you used the word "internet" rather than "network" does the system still have network connectivity to other systems on the [LAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_area_network), either by a cabled or a WiFi connection? How did you turn off the Internet connectivity?

Comment: @moonpoint Disable your wireless adapter in 'Device Manager' and unplug your network cable from RJ45 slot.

Comment: I was only working off of wireless, I disabled the wireless adapter.  I did not however monkey with the NTP, but I figured if I did not have internet connectivity it shouldn't matter?